# Is it possible to create a template that generates a fully const implicitly convertible struct from another struct?

Tags: c++

I have a problem where I need to bundle an ID with a reference/pointer to a value in C++, e.g.:

```
struct ProductWithID {
    int id;
    Product* product;
}
```

Sometimes I want to use this with a mutable `Product*` so the above will work, but other times I want to pass this to functions when I originally have a `const Product*`. But now, because I bundled the `Product*` into a struct, a function that previously looked like:

```
void HandleProduct(int id) {
    const Product* product = GetProductByID(id); // API returns const Product*
    MyFunction(id, product);
}

void MyFunction(int id, const Product* product);
```

...can not just be written as:

```
void HandleProduct(int id) {
    const Product* product = GetProductByID(id);
    MyFunction(ProductWithID{id, product}); // Error: Cannot cast const Product* to Product*
}

void MyFunction(const ProductWithID product);
```

...since `const ProductWithID` only has a `Product *const` not a `const Product*`. I could create a completely new type called `ConstProductWithID` and have custom constructors, including implicit cast from ProductWithID, but this feels like boilerplate.

So it would be nice if I could use template magic to simulate the language having a `deep_const` attribute, like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct deep_const {
    // ... template magic goes here ...
}

void MyFunction(deep_const<ProductWithID> product);
```

What `deep_const` would do is enumerate all the members of T and declare them fully const. Not just const in terms of pointer, but make whatever the pointers point to const as well. And then also add an implicit constructor, and maybe even aggregate initialization so it's looks, feels and smells like a regular C++ struct. Is this possible? Other suggestions welcome.

Comment: But... what for? Instead make the members private and write accessor functions.

Comment: You might want to clarify "when I have a `const Product*`" - add example code which has that, and calls a function. And shows how it doesn't work (a compilation error, I guess).

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't see how that solves the problem. Even if members are private, two different classes are needed to represent holding a mutable pointer or const pointer, respectively.

Comment: no you dont need two classes. The mutators are non-`const` and cannot be called on  `const` objects

Comment: " the following won't work:" you should make more clear what exactly does "not work". I mean we can guess what you mean, but still it is not completely clear

Comment: No, this is not possible. You'll have to settle for something less general, such as two class templates (one with a pointer-to-const, other with a pointer-to-nonconst, and a conversion operator between them).

Comment: But why do you want the pointer be pointing to const? It doesn't change anything. It does not change the data. If you want to disable _accessing_ the data behind the pointer, then write _accessors_.

Comment: I want the pointer to point to const so I can initialize the bundled ProductWithID with a const Product* like I explained in my question.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Why did you delete your answer? I think the const_cast idea was actually pretty good and I would have accepted it unless someone came up with something better.

Comment: @HannesLandeholm the const cast idea was actually pretty bad ;). See here: https://godbolt.org/z/dhazh1cv5. I am not completely sure but it smells like undefined behavior. Maybe not in this example, but the door is wide open

Comment: the quesiton is not perfectly clear. We propose you solutions, you answer "no because ...". Try to prepare a [mcve] that highlights the issue, then we need not discuss

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 You could delete copy constructor and have a static method for that too, but it makes it slightly less useful. I think it's the only loophole but yeah, it's kind of opening the door for UB possibilities.

Comment: just an idea that came to my mind: perhaps you can make use of a container (eg a vector) that holds only a single element, encapsulate it and only provide access to an iterator. Containers do have `iterator`s and `const_iterator`s with const-correctness. Didn't think it trough completely but it might go somewhere

Comment: You where on the right track, I actually ended up using std::tuple, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I solved this by utilizing the nice property that a `std:tuple` with type `T` at position `N` is implicitly convertible to another tuple with type `const T` at position `N`:

```
template<typename T>
class Keyed : public std::tuple<int, T*> {
 public:
  using std::tuple<int, T*>::tuple;

  int id() const {
    return std::get<0>(*this);
  }

  T* value() const {
    return std::get<1>(*this);
  }
};
```

This gives me a struct-like type with named parameters (using accessors) and I can convert from non-const to const implicitly, e.g.:

```
Keyed<Product> product;
Keyed<const Product> product2 = product; // Not an error!
```